# Can halogens show -3 or -5 or -7 oxidation state. Why?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electronic-configuration, oxidation-state, periodic-trends, halogens

I mean can we think it like if the electrons get excited into the d orbitals and because there are now more than one unpaired electron, why does it only loose them and why don't they accept more than one electrons?

Comment: Welcome to the chemistry site of the StackExchange (SE) network.  Be aware that laconic, not elaborated questions are usually closed on the SE.  
The site expects that you include the compact summary of your related current knowledge, involving your conclusion of searching for existing related  info or answers. It would prevent others to tell you what you already know or what you could easily find yourself. Effort not shown may be considered as effort not done, possibly leading to the question closure. [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Multiple negatively charged ions are possible when the final ion respects the octet rule. This is the case for $\ce{O^{2-}, N^{3-}, C^{4-}}$. But halogens needs only one electron to follow the octet rule. They cannot hold more than 1 electron.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59146/is-it-possible-for-halogens-to-show-oxidation-states-less-than-1

Comment: @Poutnik - just a comment, but 'laconic' may not be a common vocabulary word for many folks who don't have English as a first language (and indeed, even for those who do).

Comment: @JonCuster I do not have EN a a primary language. It is rather a part of background cultural knowledge, it is not an English word, coming from Laconia/Lacedaemonia = ancient Sparta. They sent to king Philip of Macedonia a short answer: 'If...." Since then comes the adjective laconic as extremely short and no descriptive.

Comment: @Poutnik - I understand that, but again a simpler, more common word might be easier for many folks to understand.

Comment: @JonCuster I admire Poutnik's canned comment and I think it's been thought out pretty well. Shall "*laconic*" be unknown to the reader, the follow-up phrase "*not elaborated questions*" will do just fine. Besides, I find it to be a beautiful word (next to cellar door level ([YouTube — Donnie Darko Cellar Door Scene](https://youtu.be/oRPG81gOMIg))), and, a foreigner from the Eastern Bloc, I also have no issues with it as there is also a cognate word in my first language (cf. Russian «***лакон**ичный*»). Finally, dumbing down the language won't do any good for anyone.

Comment: @andselisk - personally, I've always preferred 'pithy' to 'laconic'. I love the richness of the English language, but if the goal of SE is to communicate broadly then one should ask if their word choice is helping of hindering such communication. It isn't dumbing it down, it is making a choice to use widely understood vocabulary.

Comment: @JonCuster That's a fair point, can't argue with that. Although, since we cannot censor each other's vocabulary (well, at least as long as it doesn't become vulgar), let me suggest the following to resolve this little conflict: post a comment using  preferred words if you can get ahead of Poutnik — this way you deliver the message to OP the way *you* like it, and his exquisite choice of words will be a stimulus to do it faster and more often:)

Comment: @JonCuster I admit I do not know the word "pithy" at all, but searching for it, it looks it has quite different meaning to laconic. The latter, translated to Czech, is just "lakonický",  in German, "lakonische", in French "laconique", Italian "laconico", Spanish "lacónico", Swedish "lakonisk", Hungarian laconicus, Finnish lakoninen, so it seems to me like an international word.

Comment: @Poutnik - 'international' in the sense of deriving from classical Greek and Latin and thus spreading across Europe readily (pithy is more localized, coming from Old English). There are many languages less influenced by Western Europe classics education. I don't mean to censor, quite the opposite - I'm trying to make it easier for people to figure out what comments mean.

Comment: @JonCuster I am aware that influence on e.g. SE Asia languages is lower, but in spite of that, I think there is bigger chance they would know laconic than pithy. Its usage escaped from classic education.

Answer (score 1):

Different atoms/molecules/ions combine to gain more stability always. Any specie will not ever accept or gain electrons naturally that will lead to increase in their potential energy (i.e., less stability). Thus, halogens only need one electron to complete their octet and attain noble gas configuration. So, they always prefer to accept one electron only. If anyhow they accepts more than one electron, then their Potential energy will increase leading to the loss of electron, and thus they will again have accepted one electron in overall process. Thus, we always say that halogens can only accept one electron naturally.